# Removing cross-domain Distribution Lists from an AD user

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm writing a script to disable users for our security team but I'm a bit hung up on distribution lists(DL). I have it correctly cycle through every DL but when it gets to one on one of our association's domains, I get an error that the server is not willing to process the request. I've seen a workaround using ADSI and the LDAP filter but that didn't work for me at all. I also found that this issue used to be caused by a weak password/strong password policy but the password policy is the same across all domains so I don't think that's the case.

EDIT- Here is the code I use for the DL portion of the script:

```
$user = Get-QADUser -Identity "$domain\$account"
$dList = Get-QADMemberof $user
Write-Output "The following distribution lists were removed from $domain\$account: `n"    | Out-File -filepath $output
foreach($dL in $dList){
    if ($dL.DN -match "OU=Distribution Lists"){
        out-file -filepath $output -inputobject $dL -Append
        remove-QADGroupMember $dL.DN -member $user
    }
}
```

Comment: First post your code for a start

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover Code posted